# Change circle color on selection in a line chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart and I have one question:

How can I change the circle color on the one that the user clicks?

Here is what I have so far in my `OnChartValueSelectedListener`:

```
lineChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry entry, int i, Highlight highlight) {
            LocalBroadcastManager manager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext());
            Intent intent = new Intent(NewMainActivity.DIARY_ACTION);
            intent.putExtra("date", points.get(highlight.getXIndex()).getDate());
            manager.sendBroadcast(intent);
  ////////////////Here I want to change the color//////////////
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer I found is to extract a class field called `myHighlight` and update it in the listener like this:

```
lineChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry entry, int i, Highlight highlight) {
            LocalBroadcastManager manager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext());
            Intent intent = new Intent(NewMainActivity.DIARY_ACTION);
            intent.putExtra("date", points.get(highlight.getXIndex()).getDate());
            manager.sendBroadcast(intent);
            myHighlight = highlight.getXIndex();
            valuesCount = new int[lineChart.getValueCount()];
            setClickedPointGraphColor(valuesCount, clickedGraphPointColor);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {

        }
    });
```

Then I wrote a method `setClickedPointGraphColor()` where I set the colors of the circles to match the state of `myHighlight`:

```
public void setClickedPointGraphColor(int[] valuesCount, int color) {
    for (int i =0; i < valuesCount.length; i++){
        if (i == myHighlight){
            valuesCount[i] = color;
        } else {
            valuesCount[i] = regularGraphPointColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Since I have now updated the dataset, I would need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: hello can you post with some details what is NewMainActivity?